# Flot Customizing tooltip Plugin

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, flot, styling

been doing well getting into Flot and using the plugins but I've come to a problem and its my lack of programming knowledge. If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

I'm trying to customize the tooltip but I can't seem to link the id: "flotTip"  to the css styling. I have the grid as **hoverable** and added in the id: "flotTip" and set the defaultTheme to false.

```
grid: { hoverable: true, borderWidth: {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 2, left: 0}, borderColor: {bottom: "rgb(180,180,180)"}},

tooltip: true, tooltipOpts: { id: "flotTip", content: "%s %y %x", shifts: {x: 10,y: 20}, defaultTheme: false,} });
```

The CSS

```
.flotTip {padding: 3px 5px;background-color: "rgba(250,100,100,0.5)";color: #000;box shadow: 0 0 10px #555;border: 2px solid #000;-webkit-border-radius: 2px;-moz-border-radius: 2px;border-radius: 2px;}
```

Any direction would help.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector for an id is `#flotTip`.

`.flotTip` is for classes.

Comment: Thank you for this - at some point I did have this in the CSS but I must have something else wrong in the settings when I tried it.